# How to show loader instead of Error page Loading in jquerymobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, loader

I am developing hybrid Mobile application by using intel xdk and jquerymobile for UI. i have an ajax form submission which means i have two logins so that i am using tabs(2). First we will take first tab, i just enter username,password and click button it will check whether the username and password is correct or not in Database(during checking process i am adding loader) if it is correct it will redirect into next page otherwise it will show error message. Everything is working fine

**This is my html code**

```
   <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#one" class="ui-btn-active" data-ajax="false">Pre-school</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">Daycare</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
    <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
         <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
         <form name="loginform"  method="post">
             <div id = "container">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                  <label for="username">User name:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="usr" id="username">
                  <label for="password">Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" name="pword" id="password">
             </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
              <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="remember" class="custom" />
                 <label for="remember">Remeber Me</label>
              </fieldset>
           </div>
            <button id="submit" >Login</button>
          </form>        

          </div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

**This is my javascript code**

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {           
         $.mobile.loading('show',{
              text: 'Loading...',
              textVisible: true,
              theme: 'a',
               html: ""
         });
    });

    $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    });

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var u = window.localStorage["username"];  
     var p= window.localStorage["password"]; 

     $('#username').val(u);
     $('#password').val(p);   

        $('#submit').click(function(){

              un = document.loginform.usr.value;
              pw = document.loginform.pword.value;

                  $.ajax({
                        type :'GET',
                        url  :'http://example.com/login.php',
                        data : {username : un, password : pw},
                        beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
                        complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
                        success: function (data) {
                         sessionStorage.setItem('uname', un);
                         if ($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
                             var username = un;
                             var password = pw;
                           window.localStorage["username"]=username;  
                           window.localStorage["password"]=password;            
                         }
                         status = JSON.stringify(data);
                         var re = /[ ,]*"([^"]+)"|([^,]+)/g;
                         var match;
                         while (match = re.exec(status)) {
                             var text = match[1] || match[2];
                             $('ol').append($('<li>').text(text));
                            }
                            if(text === "1"){
                                window.location = "./homepage.html";
                            }
                            else if(text === "0"){    
                              intel.xdk.notification.alert("Invalid username and password", "Error", "Ok");
                             }
                            else{
                              intel.xdk.notification.alert(text, "Error", "Ok");    

                            }
                        }

                    });

                });
         });
```

**My Problem:-**
Sending request to server and get response everything is working fine but my problem is when i click login button it is showing **Error page Loading** instead of my loader

**My requirement:-**
When i click login button it should show loader instead of **Error page Loading** . i implemented loader but still it is showing "Error page Loading" i think this is some UI problem because my ajax code is working fine except this UI problem Could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the application on server or any mobile platform directly ?
If not ,then run it on the server like wampa .
And why are you using **window.location = ./homepage.html**
rather than use changePage method

```
$.mobile.changePage( "./homepage.html")
```

You are getting Error page Loading message means JQM is not able to load page may be due to cross origin issue. Try to run it on server.
Or may be paste log or create a plunker.

Comment: first chek whats error on the chrome console by running app in browser.